# How to get a list of post types that "support" various things such as page-attributes?

Tags: custom-post-types, support, page-attributes

When you [register a post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) you can pass an array of arguments that it "supports." (For example, "page-attributes," "author," "editor," etc.)

I see that [get_post_types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) has some args you can filter by, but how can I filter those that "support" specific features such as "page-attributes" or "author"? I realize I could run a loop to filter after the fact, but can this be done without an extra step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. Here's how:

```
get_post_types( array('supports' => array('page-attributes')), 'names', 'OR');
```

This Trac ticket provides some explanation as to why that last parameter—the 'OR'—is necessary: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17620

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm running into the same thing as GaryJ (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17620#comment:2). It's appears to be returning all posts—those that do and don't provide support. I'm just going to stick with subsequent loop using post_type_supports() for now.